# Plotting nonlinear regression in R with logistic growth

Tags: r

I have been working with the CDC FluView dataset, retrieved by this code:

```
library(cdcfluview)
library(ggplot2)
NEflu <- get_flu_data("census", "1", "ilinet", years=2009)
```

What I am trying to do is plot the number of providers versus the total number of ILI patients (NUM..OF.PROVIDERS vs ILITOTAL). I was able to generate the model using this code:

```
    z <- glm(NUM..OF.PROVIDERS ~ ILITOTAL, family = poisson(link="log"), data = NEflu)
    summary(z)
```

My first question is, is poisson the correct family for this data possion?

My ultimate goal here is to generate a plot of this data with a line of best fit. It appears to be a logistic growth model from this code:

```
    qplot(ILITOTAL, NUM..OF.PROVIDERS, data=NEflu)
```

Here is my attempt at generating the fitted line, with the error I received:

```
    ggplot(NEflu, aes(x=ILITOTAL,y=NUM..OF.PROVIDERS)) + geom_smooth()
    Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
    invalid graphics state
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE: I do not think using ggplot is going to get me the fitted model I am looking for. Is there a way to use nls() to accomplish this?

Comment: Run `dev.off()` to reset the graphics device, and then try the plot code again. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, that did work, thank you. However the graph is just one smooth line, rather than a line of best fit for all the data points. Do you know how to amend this?

Comment: This isn't a `ggplot` issue. `ggplot` can plot the output of any model you create. However, `geom_smooth` by default uses `loess` (locally weighted regression). To plot the equivalent of your model, do the following: `geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="poisson"))`.

Comment: To satisfy yourself that this is really the output of your model, you can also plot the predictions of your model directly. To get predictions, do `pred.data = data.frame(ILITOTAL=NEflu$ILITOTAL, pred=predict(z, type="response"))`. Then, to plot the model fit, add this to your ggplot code: `geom_line(data=pred.data, aes(ILITOTAL, pred))`.